# What technique should be used to cluster urban areas

Tags: r, clustering

I am new to clustering algorithms. I want to cluster road junctions based on traffic, that is, intersections which have traffic between each other should be in one cluster. I also have a similarity matrix, in which am using traffic between junctions as my similarity measure, I came across single linkage algorithm, should I go with it?

Comment: Welcome to CV! You might have more luck obtaining a useful answer if you give a fuller description of your aims. For instance, what use do you plan to make of these clusters? Do you need a certain number of clusters, and if so, why?

Comment: I want to group related junctions together, based on traffic between them

Comment: That much was clear :) what isn't clear is the form and scope of your data, and what use you hope to make of these clusters. For instance, one can cluster for exploratory analysis or as part of a predictive process; these are distinct. Some algorithms require choosing the number ahead of time; others do not. In any case, you are more likely to get useful answers if you edit your question to include this information. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You are not describing a clustering problem.

Instead, you are describing the **transitive closure** of the relation "has traffic inbetween". Essentially, you are looking for the **connected components**.

This is indeed related to single-linkage clustering, but quite a bit simpler.

I don't think you'll get satisfactory results.

Comment: what should I go for then?

Comment: Depends on your data and objective.

Comment: +1 - the fact that all roads are inter-connected suggests a different strategy is in order.

Comment: I need to separate "strongly" connected junctions, in order to apply different controlling techniques to each cluster

Comment: Well, try to find a definition of "strongly" then, first. Most likely, this will then also lead to a strategy. Don't expect magic from clustering algorithms.